# display grid - background has a white gap on the right side

Tags: css, grid

```css
.parent{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:50% 50%;
grid-gap:5px;
width:50%;
height:54px;
background:gold;
}

.left, .right{border:2px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<div class='left'></div>
<div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

Why there is a white vertical gap on the right side, 2 pixels or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the width of a grid item with percents doesn't account for the `grid-gap`, so 50% + 5px + 50% exceeds the width of the grid (100%).

Use [`fr` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#The_fr_Unit) instead of percents to fix this problem:

```css
.parent{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
grid-gap:5px;
width:50%;
height:54px;
background:gold;
}

.left, .right{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='left'></div>
    <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do with the grid-gap property. It's pushing the child element to the right, without extending the background. The grid-gap is 5 pixels, the white gap takes up 3 pixels, and the 2 pixel border accounts for the rest of the gap.

The easiest solution would be to set the background to the child elements. I haven't used grid enough to know any grid-specific solutions.